# Why can I modify state without action in mobx strict mode?

Tags: mobx

I imported `configure` from the mobx package and applied `enforceActions` as true. Now, components won't re-render if the mobx state is modified without action.

But whenever, I click on either button to increase or decrease the count in mobx state, I don't receive an error.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { observable, configure } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
configure({ enforceActions: true }); // components won't re-render if state is modified without action

const appState = observable({
  count: 0,
  incCount: () => {
    appState.count += 1;
  },
  decCount: () => {
    appState.count -= 1;
  },
});

const Counter = observer((props) => (
  <section>
    {props.appState.count}
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.appState.incCount}>Add</button>
      <button onClick={props.appState.decCount}>Dec</button>
    </div>
  </section>
));

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Counter appState={appState} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Why am I not seeing an error message which says that a regular function cannot modify state and only actions can?

My [github](https://github.com/develijahlee/react-mobx-app)

Comment: `incCount` and `decCount` are automatically turned into actions in your example, [it seems to be working fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-brook-9jcrp?file=/src/index.js). `enforceActions` should also be `"observed"`, `"never"`, `"always"`, not a boolean.

Comment: How does `incCount` and `decCount` automatically turn into actions? Does `observable` just do it for me automatically, including making `count` an observable?

Comment: The documentation states that ["The `source` object will be cloned and all members will be made observable, similar to how it would be done by `makeAutoObservable`"](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#observable). Without explicitly annotating a member, ["any (inherited) member that contains a function value will be annotated with `autoAction`](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#makeautoobservable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`incCount` and `decCount` are made into `action`s automatically in your example.

The source object you give as argument to `observable` will be cloned and have all its members made observable. Any `get`ers will be annotated with `computed`, and any member that contains a function value will be annotated with `autoAction` (i.e. made into an `action`).

**Example**

```js
const appState = observable({
  // observable
  count: 0,
  // computed
  get doubleCount() {
    return appState.count * 2;
  },
  // actions
  incCount: () => {
    appState.count += 1;
  },
  decCount: () => {
    appState.count -= 1;
  },
});
```